# sql group by satisfying multiple conditions within the group

Tags: sql, group-by

I have a table like below:
[image]

I want to select the group which has RELB_CD =9093 and INFO_SRC_CD with 7784. Both conditions should be present in the group. In the table below my output should be the group with id=139993690.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation with `having`:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having sum(case when relb_cd = 9093 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when info_src_cde = 7784 then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```

Comment: query is not returning any results. Please note that relb_cd = 9093 and  info_src_cd = 7784 are in different rows.

Comment: This query deals with values scattered over mutliple rows & returns the expected answer based on your example data. If it doesn't something else is causing that.

Comment: @ushrani Try with single quotes on 9093 and 7784

Comment: Yes I added quotes, still no luck

Comment: @ushrani . . . You should set up a db fiddle.

Comment: The query works, there was something else which caused the problem and I corrected it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

hey use this code hope this will help you.
you have to ignore the date column because that one is not allowing to group

select id,fisc_ind, sum(sls_amt),relb_cd,info_scop,info_src_cd from yourtable group by id,fisc_ind,relb_cd,info_scop,info_src_cd

Answer (score 0):

Another working answer. If your data are large, you could compare both GL's and this working answer and see which runs faster for you. I honestly don't know which is faster. This was slightly faster with a very short set of data.

```
    select id
    from table1
    where relb_cd = 9093
    intersect
    select id
    from table1
    where info_src_cd = 7784
```